# Problems with moving my Wordpress site to another domain/server

Tags: sql, wordpress, copy, move

I'm having problems moving a wordpress site from one domain to another. I've searched  the site but couldn find a useful answer for my situation.

Here's what i did:

I made a backup of the website. Then i exported the database.
Then i installed Wordpress on the other domain.
Then i copied all my Wordpress files of the old website on the new server overwriting the new installation. Then i deleted everything from the database on the new server and imported the database of the old server. Then i changed the database name and bpassword in the wp-config file.

So i did all this but the new site isn't working, and i don't know where it went wrong? 
So i'd like to start over, but what should i do different?

Thankyou for your help!

Comment: what error it throwing It would help us to find out what is the wrong. Is it pointing to the old site or what happen when you hit the new url

Comment: Belongs to serverfault or superuser.

Comment: Try this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933075/migrating-wordpress-3-0-1-from-one-server-to-another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thing you need to do is update 2 fields in the database to the correct domain.

It can be done a few different ways.

Method 1:

Add this line to your wp-config.php file, then visit http://yournewdomain.com/wp-admin.php and log in.  This will force the update:

```
define('RELOCATE',true);
```

After you log in, you should remove that line.

Method 2:

Add these 2 lines to your theme's functions.php file found at wp-content/themes/themename/functions.php

```
update_option('siteurl','http://example.com/blog');
update_option('home','http://example.com/blog');
```

After that, you need to update the GUID for each post.  In phpMyAdmin or from the mysql command line issue this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE (
guid,
'http://exampleoldsiteurl.com',
'http://examplenewsiteurl.com');
```

replace exampleoldsite and examplenewsite with the respective domains.

All of this info can be found at http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Answer (score 4):

You can run these sql queries in phpmyadmin to change URLs in the database after the move for site options, post URLs and URLs in  post/page content:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://olddomain.com','http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
```

**4/22/2014 Edit: this is a much better solution that won't break PHP serialized data:** [interconnectit.com WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

Answer (score 2):

You will probably need to edit some fields in your database and update the settings in the admin area. There is quite a nice guide here

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_to_a_New_Server

I think the easiest way is probably:

> - Install a new Wordpress blog
> - Go on old blog Admin panel. Here, in Manage > Export select "all" in menu
>     Restrict Author.
> - Click on Download Export File
> - In new blog go on Manage > Import, choose Wordpress item.
> - In the page that will be shown, select the file just exported. Click
>     Upload file and Import
> - It will appear a page. In Assign Authors, assign the author to users
>     that already exist or create new ones.
> - Click on Submit
> - At the end, click on Have fun

Comment: Hi thanks. I started over and did this. Now i have all the content in the standard wordpress theme. Do i now overwrite all the files in the ftp?

Comment: You only need to copy the wp-content folder, which contains your themes, plugins and uploaded files.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of installing Wordpress on new server. Copy old files to new server, import database and change wp-config. I found this helpful [How to Transfer a WordPress website to another Host](http://top10-websitehosting.co.uk/how-to-transfer-a-wordpress-website-to-another-host/)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a tool available for those who are not confident running SQL update scripts, found at:

[Search and Replace for WordPress DB](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

Remember to delete files after performing the desired actions to the DB, because the script exposes DB username/password found in wp-config.php ;)