# Moving Wordpress site to new server/domain | getting asked to reinstall WP

Tags: wordpress

I'm getting asked to reinstall Wordpress (standard 5 minute install) after moving a site to a new server and domain name.

http://kevineikenberry.com

Testing URL:

http://keg.brettatkin.com

I've checked the wp_config and the new db settings are correct and working - I set up a test page that pulls records from the db.

I've done must of the things listed in this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367058/problems-with-moving-my-wordpress-site-to-another-domain-server) such as running a couple of queries to update the domain name.

One additional thing I did do was change the table extension to something other than wp_

Any help would be awesome.  I'm at a loss and must be missing something stupid.

Thanks

Brett

Comment: I did something wrong with changing the table extension.  I pulled in the unchanged db and everything worked fine....

Comment: (Sorry for the delay...)  It did work once I started over.  Not sure what I screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

you chanced the prefix of your tables, if you do this there are DB record which need to be changed, also you  have to change it in `config.php`

take a look at this:
http://digwp.com/2010/10/change-database-prefix/

Answer (score 0):

You have changed the table prefix, that means you have different tables and your wp-config settings will not work, if you have changed your tables prefix also update it in wp-config file, save and check it again.